# Parsing date form dd-MM-yyyy to dd MMM yyyy

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to parse dd-MM-yyyy date format into dd MMM yyyy I get the reference but it cannot convert date in a proper manner it mismatches the date and month.

Suppose my date is

```
string dat = "11-01-2019"
```

and I am using

```
string date = DateTime.Parse(dat).ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
```

but it returns ***01 Nov 2019***. But actually, it is ***11 Jan 2019*** because the format of date is dd-MM-yyyy I don't understand how to correct it any method of parsing I am using it returns 01 Nov 2019 that is wrong. Please help me to resolve the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to specify the culture the date is formatted for. I'm assuming UK here:

```
var ukCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-gb");
string dat = "11-01-2019";
string date = DateTime.Parse(dat, ukCulture).ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
Console.WriteLine(date);
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/ROKMQ30425)

Note that you'll get a `FormatException` if you enter an invalid date here, so it might be better to use `TryParse`:

```
var ukCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-gb");
string dat = "11-01-2019";
DateTime parsedDate;
if (DateTime.TryParse(dat, ukCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out parsedDate))
{
    string date = parsedDate.ToString("dd MMM yyyy");
    Console.WriteLine(date);
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("invalid date");
}
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/DUR57210)

Answer (score 0):

Adding to John's great answer, here's a list of CultureInfo codes for reference:
http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/